# BSPlayer stops playing after some time

Tags: music, background-process

I have the BSPlayer Free for Android. When I have a playlist playing and switch to another app, or lock the phone, the music keeps playing for about a minutes and then stops.

How do I change that so it keeps playing?

Answer (score 0):

Since the VM decides when to stop the Application in order to Save\clear memory for other applications you cant decide which application you can keep in the forground.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think this is true. There are many applications that keep playing after switching to another app or locking the screen. For example I use runkeeper a lot which does just that.